# CSS Error when using jQuery's gt() selector?

Tags: jquery, css

I've noticed that Firefox throws me a warning on the following jQuery code:

```
$("li.example div.code:gt(4)").hide();
```

CSS Error: Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element 'gt'.

According to jQuery, it all should be correct. And it works, but I wonder how to fix this error for cleanness sake.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it will work by class reference, I don't see a reason why your code wouldn't work, could you post your div code because it seems to work fine for me, but Im using IE

```
$("li.example td.code:gt(4)").hide();
```

the above code will work because it will look for the 4th div and hide all the divs after that one, remembering that the index starts a **0**

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/eteyi)

Comment: thanks! My code works, it's just Firefox gives CSS error (as a warning). It's a shame it is not considered a correct way when it performs as required.

Comment: I just found that your example gives the same CSS Error. It must be something different!

Comment: my example gives an error in firefox,? if so can you post your div code that you're trying it on?

Comment: Hi TStamper, yes - your example, *on your* webpage gives the same error!

Comment: @kimka- did you try to run my actual demo in your browser, or just the line I put up?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox will throw this *warning* (not error!) because it attempts the CSS selector which it doesn't think is valid.  That's ok though, you can **ignore this warning**, you know it works, just ignore the console error in this instance.  It'll do this for *any* selector it doesn't recognize.

[You can read the jQuery nabble discussion on the same topic here](http://old.nabble.com/using-%22:gt%22---Firefox-error-console-annouces-an-error-td26905317s27240.html).